# Import Parametric Sweep data from LTSPice into Matlab

Tags: simulation, ltspice, matlab, data

In LTSpice, I am running transient simulations with input 2 parameters (Amplitude and Frequency) being swept. The initial graph of all the data looks like this:

[image: Initial LTSPice data]
Obviously it is hard to tell what is going on. I would like to import the large simulation data into Matlab for analysis, where I can separate the data into individual waveforms - each corresponding to an amplitude and frequency that was swept.

I found a [file online](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23394-fast-import-of-compressed-binary-raw-files-created-with-ltspice-circuit-simulator?focused=5113448&tab=function) that implements the LTspice2Matlab command that imports a RAW file, however it cannot isolate each waveform as I expected. Are RAW files stored in a manner that each data point is paired with its amplitude and frequency? If so, how can I properly import this into Matlab?

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can convert the raw format to ASCII with ltsputil.exe.  Look [here](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/364022/ltsputil_help.txt) for details.